# Custom sorting of Funnel Chart on Formula Field

Tags: dashboard

I am trying to create a Funnel chart in a Dashboard, starting from a report. If I choose a specific grouping, I can add the report to a dashboard but I cannot specify the sort order. When instead I add a bucket column to provide a custom order, when I add the report to the Dashboard I cannot change its type.

Is it possible to have custom-ordered Funnel charts?

Comment: If the grouping is based on a picklist, it sometimes depends on the picklist order of the items

Comment: Can’t use picklist